# How to inject a service in a view component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a layout component where I need to inject a service. but the service is undefined . Here's my code :

```
import {BaseLayout, LogEvent, Layout} from "ts-log-debug";
import {formatLogData} from "@tsed/common/node_modules/ts-log-debug/lib/layouts/utils/inspectUtils.js";
import { StorageService } from './StorageService';
import { IBasicLayoutConfiguration } from "@tsed/common/node_modules/ts-log-debug/lib/layouts/interfaces/BasicLayoutConfiguration";


@Layout({name: "customJson"})
export class JsonLayout extends BaseLayout {

  constructor(config : IBasicLayoutConfiguration , private storageService : StorageService) { 
    super(config);
  }

  transform(loggingEvent: LogEvent, timezoneOffset?): string {
      const log = {

           Id:{ Id: () => {
                       return this.storageService && this.storageService.getId() || '';
                  },
                },

          context: context
      };
      log.data = log.data.map((data) => formatLogData([data]));
      return JSON.stringify(log) + (this.config["separator"] || "");
  };

}
```

I have the service in the providers array in the app.module.ts file. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is your StorageService annotated with @Injectable()

Comment: why isn't your component annotated with @Component() ??

Comment: the storage service is annotated with @Service()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service,that needs to be injected into the angular component:

1) create a service, that is annotated with @Injectable(), like below

```
@Injectable()
export class StudyService
```

2) you have to inject that in the component constructor like you are already doing with StorageService :

```
 constructor(private studyService: StudyService){}
```

Comment: do I need to add the @Injectable() annotation ? because the service is used in other components the way it is , with the annotation @Service()

Comment: yes try that. that is how we inject service in components

Comment: refer to this for more dependency injection
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: this is backend with tsed , not really an angular project

Comment: If it is backend rest api, then what you can do is, call those apis using HttpClient from angular service
https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Injectable()
export class StudyService
constructor(http: HttpClient){}
getStudyDetails():Observable<someObject>{
return this.http.get<someObject>(url)
}

Comment: you can do something like like and call getStudyDetails from your component

Comment: after some debugging , the constructor is completely skipped in my component , that's why the service is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200733/discussion-between-pradeep-and-m-maria).